# Bluetooth mic Action Script

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi I am trying to make an application using actionscript. I am trying to detect headset microphone using `Microphone.getMicrophone();` but I am only getting the mic of the device and not the mic of the Bluetooth headset.

Is there a way to use Bluetooth headset's mic as audio input in Action Script?

Comment: Can you please add some code to your question?

Comment: [getMicrophone returns the default microphone that you have defined in flash settings](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#getMicrophone()) Alternatively you can pass an integer to choose which microphone you want. Please read the documentation carefully.

Comment: I have already tried changing the index to a different value but to no avail. I have checked Microphone.names.length property but it only gives 1. Even though the Bluetooth headset is connected to the device.

Comment: @MangJose sounds like you should scan for extra bluetooth device not extra microphone device. Not sure how you'll get data from it unless there's a way it can send bytes back to you (eg using **std in/out**)...